# Sublime text 3 find and replace in selection without clicking the button

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using ST3 with vintage mode. When selecting some lines and pressing alt+shift+f (Mac OSX) I get the find and replace dialog at the bottom of the screen.

BUT, I have to remove my hand from the keyboard, reach for the mouse and click the little "In selection" button...

...is there some way for sublime to realize that I have made a selection and have that button clicked by default?

Comment: I have posted all the missing / undocumented commands for toggling options in the find / replace / find in files panels [in this post on the ST forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keyboard-shortcut-toggle-wrap-and-highlight-matches-in-find-dialog/22559/3?u=mattst). HTH.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try setting:

```
"auto_find_in_selection": true,
```

From my understanding, this will automatically use 'in selection' if you have non-empty selection when goes into find box.

[Edit]
Note, you generally set this settings in "Preferences.sublime-settings".  You can open this setting by "Ctrl+Shift+P", and select "Preferences: Settings - User".

Comment: where can we set this? which file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Hope it will be useful one day to someone.